# Custom Radio Buttons Won't Display in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, radio-button, custom-controls

I'm using Screw Default Buttons (http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/) to customize the radio buttons and checkboxes in a client project (https://artofgivingfl.com/make-gift).

I've tried everything I can think of, but it just won't display the custom buttons correctly in Firefox. It's not registering the clicks properly to change the image to the selected state.

It seems to work fine in every other browser.

Ideas?

Comment: Well, you do have structural errors in your HTML (script elements between the `</head>` and the `<body>`) which the W3 validator can't recover from. Maybe Firefox handles those errors differently.

Comment: That's because the site is built in WP, and it uses a common header, but some srcipts only reside on certain pages. That shouldn't be an issue, but I'll see if changing it does anything.

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the the problem was the radio button itself. It was present, overlaying the custom button. I changed the visibility to hidden, and it works like a charm now.